# jRuby deployment into Glassfish

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, glassfish, twitter-bootstrap-3

after I replaced the standard Bootstrap glyphicons by font-awesome my application did no longer start on Glassfish (see attached screenshot).

Even if I remove the font-awesome gem I get the same error. Glassfish complains as decribed here:

org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (LoadError) Exception loading extension `KryptcoreService`: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Stream handler unavailable due to: null

at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1082) at ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Loadable.require(/home/glassfish/glassfish/domains/xpertiseportal/applications/xpp/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251)   at ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Loadable.load_dependency(/home/glassfish/glassfish/domains/xpertiseportal/applications/xpp/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236)

I use  warbler to deploy the application.!

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add a WEB-INF/init.rb file
with the content

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift 'uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared'
require 'jopenssl'
```

see https://github.com/jruby/warbler/issues/266#issuecomment-71327274